# Define a function, that evaluates other function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I want to be able to write a Function (Operator), that gets 2 arguments. The first argument specifies the kind of "operation", the second the function on which to apply the operation. It should work with $\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ functions.

I have defined a function

`myF[t_]:= {Sin[t],Cos[t]}`

so a function that maps $\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n,$ for the case $n=2$.

Now I want to define another function, that evaluates `myF` at 0, whenever I pass `evaluate` as (first) argument.

I tried the following

`myOperator[evaluate,Fun_[t_]]:=Map[t=0][Fun]`

However, the output is

`myOperator[evaluate,{0,1}]`

So the evaluation happens, but the result is not just the vector... Can anyone help me?

Edit: Of course, I have also tried

`myOperator[evaluate,Fun_[t_]]:=Fun[0]`

Comment: You've got a number of syntax issues, but my guess based on your description is that you want `myOperator[evaluate_, fun_]: fun[0]`. Read the docs so you can understand how Mathematica functions are actually defined

Comment: Thank you, this works. But in general, how would I access the variable `t`? Like `myOperator[foo,...]=  Integrate[fun,{t,0,3}] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
ClearAll[myOperator];
myF[t_] = {Sin[t], Cos[t]}
myOperator[evaluate, f_] = f[0];
myOperator[evaluate, myF]
```

The output is:

```
{0, 1}
```